# Type of the object

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous

I try to fetch a text from a local txt file and create an array consisted of all words from the file. Just like ['this', 'is', 'a', 'sample', 'text'...]. The problem is that I cannot do anything with the resulting array. I cannot loop it with forEach or even access any item. I think I should transform the array is some way but have no idea how. [This is the screenshot of the array in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhbCg.png) 
Probably the question is quite silly, but I am very beginner at JS. Thanks.

```
const arr = []
fetch('sample.txt')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => data.split(' '))
    .then(result => arr.push(...result))
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: `response.text` or `response.json` here `.then(response => response.text())`?

Comment: how do you try to use the array and what failure are you getting?

Comment: Thank you. But the idea was to save the rsulted array and use it outside. I am searching for the solution since yesterday and still have not found anything.

Comment: to use outside of the `fetch` you can use aysnc/await as described in my answer below, but it has a ripple effect that the function you're using it in will now return a Promise

Comment: Thanks! It took me another few hours of reading/watching tutorials but now I understand how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `fetch` is asynchronous so everything in the `then` functions will not get done before your final `console.log(arr)` call.  If you want to do something with the data in the array, then it should be done within the Promise chain like this:

```
const arr = []
fetch('sample.txt')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => data.split(' '))
    .then(result => arr.push(...result))
    .then(() => {
        console.log(arr)
        arr.forEach(word => console.log(word))
    })
// outside here the array is still empty
```

If you want to use it outside then you can use `async/await` like this:

```
async function myFunction {
const arr = []
await fetch('sample.txt')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => data.split(' '))
    .then(result => arr.push(...result))
arr.forEach(word => console.log(word))
}
```

This causes processing of your function to wait until the `fetch` call (and all subsequent `then` statements) to complete before continuing. By doing this you guarantee that `arr` has been populated. Note though, that you must declare your function as `async` which means it now returns a `Promise` object and needs to be treated as asynchronous.